# Failed to connect to startum server eu1.ethermine.org

Tags: genoil

I am running genoil miner on eu1.ethermine.org and i keep getting a "Failed to connect" error. My internet connection is strong, this should not be a problem. I have been getting this error for over a week so it is not temporary.

Start.bat:

```
@echo off

setx GPU_FORCE_64BIT_PTR 0
setx GPU_MAX_HEAP_SIZE 100
setx GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS 1
setx GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
setx GPU_SINGLE_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
ethminer.exe --farm-recheck 200 -G -S eu1.ethermine.org:4444 -O <censored>.myrig
```

Log:

```
SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
Genoil's ethminer 0.9.41-genoil-1.1.7
=====================================================================
Forked from github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum
CUDA kernel ported from Tim Hughes' OpenCL kernel
With contributions from nicehash, nerdralph, RoBiK and sp_

Please consider a donation to:
ETH: 0xeb9310b185455f863f526dab3d245809f6854b4d

Found suitable OpenCL device [GeForce GTX 960M ] with 2147483648 bytes of GPU memory
  i  09:03:09|main  Connecting to stratum server eu1.ethermine.org:4444
                     X  09:03:51|stratum  Could not connect to stratum server eu1.ethermine.org : 4444 , A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
  i  09:03:51|stratum  Reconnecting in 3 seconds...
  i  09:03:54|stratum  Connecting to stratum server eu1.ethermine.org:4444
```

Specs:

GPU: GTX 960

CPU: Intel i5

OS: Windows 10

Comment: Try Delete the `.myrig` part in last line.